# Google Forms data analysis

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

i have a google form with one question.

How much water do you drink in a day?

1. 5 oz
2. 10 oz

When the User will submit the form i want to get the answer, and check, if its 5 oz i want to store result as fail and if answer is 10 , i want to store result pass on the excel sheet (along with response of the user with question (google sheet)) and send that sheet back to the User.

i have tried it Using script editor of the google sheet and all but i couldn't find a complete example explaining this complete process in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches to this.

**Approach 1 - Form API + Time-Based Trigger**
You can set up a Google App Script (GAS) and use the Forms API to get the responses from the form at some periodic time interval.  You can then process the responses by, e.g. looking at all responses that have been submitted since the last time the GAS ran, and make decisions based on those responses, which includes creating spreadsheet, sharing them with the submitter and then sending an email with a URL to the submitter.

Snippet from GAS

```
  var myForm = FormApp.openById(formId);

//load timeLastRun loaded from a e.g. script property using PropertiesService or calculate the time one time-period previous

 var responses = myForm.getResponses(timeLastRun);  

  for (var response in responses){
     var question = myForm.getItemById(itemId);

     var answer = responses[response].getResponseForItem(question) .getResponse();
     var thisSubmitter = responses[response].getRespondentEmail();

     // do some decision making

  }
```

You can get the item IDs by running something like

```
function getIds(){
    var myForm = FormApp.openById(formId);
    var items = myForm.getItems();
    for (var item in items){
      Logger.log(items[item].getId() + " " +items[item].getTitle());
    }
}
```

**Approach 2 - Google Sheet + OnSubmit Trigger**
Store everything in a Google Sheet and filter the passes (e.g. the answers that were "correct") on to another tab using, e.g., QUERY() or FILTER().

Create a GAS that is triggered to run every form submission.  Then perform the decision-making based on each individual form submission. You can grab the form data submitted by either referencing the [event object e](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) or just grabbing the last row of the form data in the spreadsheet each time.

Code Snippet:

```
function onSubmit(e){
  var response = e.values;

  var thisSubmitter = response[1]; // if the 2nd column contains the submitter's email address
  var answer = response[2|  // if the 3rd column in the spreadsheet contains the answer you're looking for
  // do some decision making

}
```

In this approach, you have to match your variables to the order of the answers or use `e.NamedValues[question]` to explicitly select the value you want to use.

**The Decision Making Part**
You mentioned you wanted to create another sheet based on the submitted answer and email the submitter.  In this case you would need to use the SpreadsheetApp Service to create another sheet and populate it with the data you want to communicate and then use the GmailApp Service to email the submitter.  If you post an attempt at this then the community here will most likely help you refine it, but I think the information in this answer is enough to get you started.